# Why am i getting this error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int?

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I am getting an error message which i attached a pic of, everything is working fine except the "attendance" part which is not showing in the view, i do not know what the problem is, i sure its something simple i am just not seeing it, please let me know where i am going wrong. Thank you.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vvn5d.png)

```
public function edit_data()
{

    $show = $_POST['id'];
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM participants_info WHERE participant_id=$show");
    $query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM participants_attendance  WHERE participant_id=$show");
    $query3 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM pcs_schedule WHERE participant_id=$show");
    $data_view= $query->row();
    $data_view2= $query2->row();
    $data_view3= $query3->row();

    trigger_error("SPECIAL".print_r($data_view, true));
    trigger_error("SEVERE".print_r($data_view2, true));
    trigger_error("RED".print_r($data_view3, true));


    $aggregate_data_view=array('participant_id'=>'',
        'First_Name'=>'','Last_Name' =>'','Function'=>'',
        'Stlc_id'=>'','Address'=>'','City'=>'','State'=>'',
        'Zip_Code'=>'','Phone_Number'=>'','Latitude'=>'','Longitude'=>'',
        'Disenrolled'=>'','Deceased'=>'','participant_att_id'=>'','Attendance_Monday'=>'',
        'Attendance_Tuesday'=>'','Attendance_Wednesday'=>'','Attendance_Thursday'=>'','Attendance_Friday'=>'',
        'Lanyard_Status'=>'','Assistive_Devices'=>'','WheelChair_Van'=>'','TransitVan_240'=>'','TransitVan_360'=>'',
        'Subaru_Impreza'=>'','Comments'=>'','pcs_id'=>'','Monday_Pick_Up'=>'','Monday_Drop_Off'=>'','Tuesday_Pick_Up'=>'',
        'Tuesday_Drop_Off'=>'','Wednesday_Pick_Up'=>'','Wednesday_Drop_Off'=>'','Thursday_Pick_Up'=>'','Thursday_Drop_Off'=>'',
        'Friday_Pick_Up'=>'','Friday_Drop_Off'=>'','Saturday_Pick_Up'=>'','Saturday_Drop_Off'=>'','Sunday_Pick_Up'=>'','Sunday_Drop_Off'=>'','Lanyard_Status'=>'','Assistive_Devices'=>'','WheelChair_Van'=>'','TransitVan_240'=>'','TransitVan_360'=>'','Subaru_Impreza'=>'','Comments'=>''
        );

    $aggregate_data_view['participant_id']=$data_view->participant_id;
    $aggregate_data_view['First_Name']=$data_view->First_Name;
    $aggregate_data_view['Last_Name']=$data_view->Last_Name;
    $aggregate_data_view['Function']=$data_view->Function;
    $aggregate_data_view['Stlc_id']=$data_view->Stlc_id;
    $aggregate_data_view['Address']=$data_view->Address;
    $aggregate_data_view['City']=$data_view->City;
    $aggregate_data_view['State']=$data_view->State;
    $aggregate_data_view['Zip_Code']=$data_view->Zip_Code;
    $aggregate_data_view['Phone_Number']=$data_view->Phone_Number;
    $aggregate_data_view['Latitude']=$data_view->Latitude;
    $aggregate_data_view['Longitude']=$data_view->Longitude;
    $aggregate_data_view['Disenrolled']=$data_view->Disenrolled;
    $aggregate_data_view['Deceased']=$data_view->Deceased;



    if($data_view2 > 0)
    {

    $aggregate_data_view['participant_att_id']=$data_view2->participant_att_id;
    $aggregate_data_view['Attendance_Monday']=$data_view2->Attendance_Monday;
    $aggregate_data_view['Attendance_Tuesday']=$data_view2->Attendance_Tuesday;
    $aggregate_data_view['Attendance_Wednesday']=$data_view2->Attendance_Wednesday;
    $aggregate_data_view['Attendance_Thursday']=$data_view2->Attendance_Thursday;
    $aggregate_data_view['Attendance_Friday']=$data_view2->Attendance_Friday;
    $aggregate_data_view['Lanyard_Status']=$data_view2->Lanyard_Status;
    $aggregate_data_view['Assistive_Devices']=$data_view2->Assistive_Devices;
    $aggregate_data_view['WheelChair_Van']=$data_view2->WheelChair_Van;
    $aggregate_data_view['TransitVan_240']=$data_view2->TransitVan_240;
    $aggregate_data_view['TransitVan_360']=$data_view2->TransitVan_360;
    $aggregate_data_view['Subaru_Impreza']=$data_view2->Subaru_Impreza;
    $aggregate_data_view['Comments']=$data_view2->Comments;
    //$aggregate_data_view['participant_id']=$data_view2->participant_id;
    }

    if($data_view3 > 0)
    {   

    $aggregate_data_view['pcs_id']=$data_view3->pcs_id;
    $aggregate_data_view['Monday_Pick_Up']=$data_view3->Monday_Pick_Up;
    $aggregate_data_view['Monday_Drop_Off']=$data_view3->Monday_Drop_Off;
    $aggregate_data_view['Tuesday_Pick_Up']=$data_view3->Tuesday_Pick_Up;
    $aggregate_data_view['Tuesday_Drop_Off']=$data_view3->Tuesday_Drop_Off;
    $aggregate_data_view['Wednesday_Pick_Up']=$data_view3->Wednesday_Pick_Up;
    $aggregate_data_view['Wednesday_Drop_Off']=$data_view3->Wednesday_Drop_Off;
    $aggregate_data_view['Thursday_Pick_Up']=$data_view3->Thursday_Pick_Up;
    $aggregate_data_view['Thursday_Drop_Off']=$data_view3->Thursday_Drop_Off;
    $aggregate_data_view['Friday_Pick_Up']=$data_view3->Friday_Pick_Up;
    $aggregate_data_view['Friday_Drop_Off']=$data_view3->Friday_Drop_Off;
    $aggregate_data_view['Saturday_Pick_Up']=$data_view3->Saturday_Pick_Up;
    $aggregate_data_view['Saturday_Drop_Off']=$data_view3->Saturday_Drop_Off;
    $aggregate_data_view['Sunday_Pick_Up']=$data_view3->Sunday_Pick_Up;
    $aggregate_data_view['Sunday_Drop_Off']=$data_view3->Sunday_Drop_Off;
    $aggregate_data_view['Lanyard_Status']=$data_view3->Lanyard_Status;
    $aggregate_data_view['Assistive_Devices']=$data_view3->Assistive_Devices;
    $aggregate_data_view['WheelChair_Van']=$data_view3->WheelChair_Van;
    $aggregate_data_view['TransitVan_240']=$data_view3->TransitVan_240;
    $aggregate_data_view['TransitVan_360']=$data_view3->TransitVan_360;
    $aggregate_data_view['Subaru_Impreza']=$data_view3->Subaru_Impreza;
    $aggregate_data_view['Comments']=$data_view3->Comments;
    //$aggregate_data_view['participant_id']=$data_view3->participant_id;
    }


    $data4view['aggregate_data_view']=$aggregate_data_view;

    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view('edit_data', $data4view);

 }
```

My View: i have included part that pertains to error only.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"   href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

 <title>

 </title>
 </head>
 <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="decontroller" class="container">

 <div id="banner" style="text-align:center; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; display:block;">

<img src="http://intranet.gfhs.local/stlc_trans/STLC-Tree-Logo-PACE.png">

</div>


<h2></h2>
<h3>Personal Information:</h3>
<div id="validation-errors">
</div>

<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" ng-submit="processRequest()">
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>ParticipantID</td>
  <td>{{edit.Stlc_id}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>First Name:<br>
  </td>
  <td>{{edit.First_Name}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Last Name:<br>
  </td>
  <td>{{edit.Last_Name}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Address:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name ="Address" ng-model="edit.Address" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Phone:</td>
  <td><input size="20" name ="phone" ng-model="edit.Phone_Number" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Assistive Devices:</td>
  <td><input name ="Assistive_Devices" ng-model="edit.Assistive_Devices" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Lanyard Code</td>
  <td>
    <input name ="Lanyard_Status" ng-model="edit.Lanyard_Status"  /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Comments</td>
  <td>
    <textarea cols="100" name="comments" ng-model="edit.Comments">.</textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Disenrolled</td>
  <td><input name="disenrolled" type="checkbox" ng-model="edit.Disenrolled" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Deceased</td>
  <td><input name="deceased" type="checkbox" ng-model="edit.Deceased" ></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>

 <h3>Days in Center<br></h3>
 <table class="table table-bordered">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>Monday</td>
  <td>Tuesday</td>
  <td>Wednesday</td>
  <td>Thursday</td>
  <td>Friday</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input name="Attendance_Monday" type="checkbox" ng-model="edit.Attendance_Monday" ></td>
  <td><input name="Attendance_Tuesday"  type="checkbox" ng-model="edit.Attendance_Tuesday" ></td>
  <td><input name="Attendance_Wednesday" type="checkbox" ng-model="edit.Attendance_Wednesday" ></td>
  <td><input name="Attendance_Thursday"  type="checkbox" ng-model="edit.Attendance_Thursday" ></td>
  <td><input name="Attendance_Friday"  type="checkbox" ng-model="edit.Attendance_Friday" ></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vvn5d.png)

Comment: And what's on line 201 and 220 in transport.php?

Comment: its the part with the "if" statements: if($data_view2 > 0) and if($data_view3 > 0)

Comment: Then the warning message is pretty obvious. The variables `$data_view2` and `$data_view3` are objects and you're comparing them against an integer i.e `0`. To get rid of the warning you could perhaps just check if the variables are set or not e.g `if (isset($data_view2))`?

Answer (score 0):

when you do this `$data_view= $query->row();`, `$data_view` becomes an object. you can check that by `var_dump($data_view)`. so you can not use it like `if($data_view > 0)` because `$data_view` is not an integer. if you are checking if `$data_view` contains any data, you can check it like this `if(count($data_view) > 0)`.
that should work. :)

Comment: The warning message seems to suggest that the variables are **not** arrays but objects.

Comment: my bad, `row()` returns only one object.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, i ended up fixing like this:  $retrieve = array( 
   'Attendance_Monday' => $_POST['Attendance_Monday']=='true'?1:0,
   'Attendance_Tuesday' => $_POST['Attendance_Tuesday']=='true'?1:0,
   'Attendance_Wednesday' => $_POST['Attendance_Wednesday']=='true'?1:0,
   'Attendance_Thursday' => $_POST['Attendance_Thursday']=='true'?1:0,
   'Attendance_Friday' => $_POST['Attendance_Friday']=='true'?1:0,